# Use a generic data object (and table) for several @OneToOne mappings

Tags: java, hibernate

Instead of having several small objects (which have mostly the same properties like ID and NAME) mapped as `@OneToOne`, I would like to have one "generic" kind of object which is mapped to a single database table, and should be referenced by a kind of discriminator column `group_id` in this case.

The code examples should make it clear what I want to achieve:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GENERAL_DATA")
public class GeneralData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private int groupId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "INVOICE")
public class Invoice {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATUS")
    private GeneralData status;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COLOR")
    private GeneralData color;
}
```

The database table structure of GeneralData should be like this:

```
group_id    id     name
-----------------------------
1           1      Active 
1           2      Processing 
1           3      Cancelled
2           1      Blue 
2           2      Green 
2           3      Red
```

Comment: did't get your question, what exactly are you asking..?

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you get rid of GeneralData entity and use simple enums in invoice entity? If you have specified Statuses / Colors it is better way.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVOICE")
public class Invoice {

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private Status         status;

    @Column(name = "COLOR")
    private Color         color;

}

public enum Status {
    ACTIVE,
    PROCESSING,
    CANCELLED
}

// ...
```

Comment: I came up with this idea as well. The problem I saw is that the names are constant when using an enum (unless I use messages from MessageSource with the enums as key), I can not sort with SQL means, and I can not add more properties (which could be easily done with GeneralData.

Comment: Ok, but your solution looks ugly. Maybe replacing groupId with enum will be a little help. But your solution causing that you can easly make mistake by referencing bad GeneralData (with wrong group id) and you will need more exception handling. What is more, I don't understand why you need statuses/colors in the database. How new statuses will be added to database? If you will be giving option to the user, I would suggest you get rid of general data and create separate entities for each parameter.
P.S. What is your real question/problem here?